# Core Data Model for Multiple Media Types?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm quite new to the world of Core Data. My application grabs movie and tv show data via an api. Both the Movie and TvShow managedObjects have similar properties. I am still a bit confused on the best way to set up my models. This is currently what I have implemented, and I'm wondering what I can do to make a more efficient model.

Would it be best to have an overall mediaObject that has the similar properties and then have movie and tvshow as a sort of subclass? (If so how could I implement it)

[image: Current Core Data Model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have two entities with similar properties it can (sometimes) make sense to use a "Parent Entity" to hold the attributes (or relationships) that they have in common.  To do this, create an Entity (such as the `MediaObject` that you propose) and define for it all the common attributes.  Then remove those attributes from the "child" Entities (`TVSeries` and `Movie`), and instead set `MediaObject` as the parent entity - this is set in the data model inspector on the right.  You should have something like this:

[image: Data Model Editor image]

I suspect there are further improvements to be made to this - eg. the `name` attribute on `TVSeries` might be equivalent to `title` on `Movie`, so could be renamed and moved to the parent `MediaObject`, etc.

A few other thoughts: your original `genre` relationship was one-many: one `Movie` could have many `Genres`, but each `Genre` could have only one `Movie`.  I think you might want to reverse this, so each `Movie` belongs to only one `Genre`, but each `Genre` can have many `Movies`, or possibly to have a many-many relationship.  Note also it's usual practice to use plural names for to-many relationships, eg. `tvShows` rather than `tvShow`.  This just makes the intent clearer.  Also I would avoid `id` as an attribute name; it's *too* generic: `mediaId`, `genreId`, etc would be better.

If you use the "Create NSManagedObject Subclasses" menu option, Xcode will create separate classes for all the entities, with the `TVSeries` and `Movie` classes each being a subclass of `MediaObject` (which is in turn a subclass of NSManagedObject).  The property definitions for each subclass reflect the attributes and relationships for the corresponding Entity.

I began with a proviso: it *can sometimes* make sense to use a Parent Entity.  The reason for the caution is that in practice, Core Data implements the parent/child entities as a single SQL table - with ALL of the attributes/relationships of the parent and all the children.  This implementation detail is hidden from you by CoreData - but there can be an impact on performance: the table will be "wide" - lots of columns - many of which will be empty since they relate to a different subentity.  You will find plenty of Q&A on Stack Overflow about this problem, with some people choosing not to use parent entities because performance is too badly affected.  You will need to assess this for yourself based on your likely volume of data, complexity of queries, etc.

Comment: Ok. This clarifies a lot. Thank! :)